# permanent preamble in bibdesk-texshop

Tags: texshop, preamble, bibdesk

I use TexShop as my bib file generator and manage it with Bibdesk (I have a mac). How do I add a command to the preamble of the bib file which will always stay there even when I update my references and save them in bibdesk? What I would like to do is add the following line to my bib file in TexShop:

```
@preamble{"\newcommand{\SortNoop}[1]{}"}
```

But every time I save the bib file after adding more references to it via bibdesk, this line disappears and I have to add it manually every time after saving. Any suggestions?

Comment: If BibDesk is not preserving your `@preamble`, please file a bug report with a trivial sample bib file. It should keep it intact, even though it doesn't allow editing. Putting it in the template is fine as a workaround, but then it's added to every bib file you save.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Bibdesk preferences under Opening and Saving, there is an option to specify "write template file at the front of every file when saving". You can use this to specify the template with your `@preamble`

[image]